# malloc int array (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c

Why I have a Segmentation fault in the last line?
I try to search but not found the solution, can anybody tell me why I have a Segmentation fault?

```
int **o_position(char **map)
{
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int **pos_o = malloc(sizeof(int *));

    for (i = 0; map[i][j] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; map[i][j] != '\n'; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == 'O')
                count++;
        }
    }
    pos_o = malloc(sizeof(int) * (count * 2));
    pos_o[0][k++] = count;
}
```

Comment: If you want a 2D array, use one. A pointer is not an array. #2345082469780923

Comment: Your second last line, where you have a second assignment `pos_o = malloc(…);` throws away all the hard work done before that, leaking memory and leaving you with incomplete data structures with uninitialized pointers which lead to your crash. It's odd to have the variable `k` set to 0 simply so that you can eventually write `pos_o[0][0] = count;` (because what you've shown is equivalent to that). You don't return a value from the function, either — that's bad.  Presumably, you're missing `return pos_o;`. And you're only allocating one `int *`...not an array on them. What are you trying to do?

Comment: In the outer loop ending condition `for (i = 0; map[i][j] != '\0'; i++)` `j` needs to be reset after each inner loop. Or perhaps you need `map[i][0] != '\0';`

Comment: Because the second-to-last line should probably be `pos_o[0] = malloc(...)`. Otherwise `pos_o[0]` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @melpomene thank you so much, and the others thanks for helping me! :)

Comment: If the answer(s) here helped you please accept one of them. This has a number of benefits for you, for the answerers and for other users of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Your `pos_o` variable (which is a pointer to a pointer variable) stores the base-address of contiguous segment of memory for 1 unit - and here the unit is actually base address of another memory location. (**And for this another memory location you are nowhere allocating memory**) I think you understand this because you have already written this line `int **pos_o = malloc(sizeof(int *));` - (here you are allocating 1 unit by `sizeof(int*)` for a pointer variable). But nowhere you have allocated memory for variable to which this pointer variable will point to.

Not allocating the memory is not a problem, but referencing the memory location without allocating the memory might result in segmentation fault.

You should have something like `pos_o[0]=malloc(sizeof(int))` (I suggest allocating it for only one integer variable as I see your variable `k` is always 0, and you are accessing only one element). Consider allocating more (appropriate amount of) memory if you have your variable `k` being modified by some logic that you have not mentioned here.

Read more about segmentation faults from [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsj).